# How to cite published university course with some uncommon entries using .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am trying to cite a course from MIT Opencouseware using a `.bib` file. The displayed reference needs to look roughly as below:

> Wierzbicki, T. 2.080J Structural Mechanics. Massachusetts Institute of
>   Technology: MIT OpenCourseWare, https://ocw.mit.edu. License: Creative
>   Commons BY-NC-SA, 2013.

As I have to deal with several references that include unusual entries (such as License), I was wondering if there is a way to simply enter the text I want to show as a paragraph in the `.bib` file, with appropriate formatting, and simply display that in the reference list. I wish to do this using a `.bib` file, as an exception to my general referencing approach, and not by calling `thebibliography`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you literally looking to reference an online lecture course? Are you maybe trying a booklet with lecture notes distributed with the course?

Comment: Well, to be specific what I really want to reference is "Lecture 6: Moderately Large Deflection Theory of Beams" of the above course. But referencing the whole course will also do. To reference the whole course the university providing it requires the format I've given in my question.

Comment: Thanks for providing these additional pieces of information. One additional question: Which bibliography style do you use? The reason I ask is that not all bibliography styles recognize, let alone know what to do with, a field called `url`.

Comment: I am currently just using the plain style but I intend to use ieee eventually

Comment: In general , for unclassifiable references the safer will be use the least  restrictive type entry (`@misc`), where all fields are optional (except the key, obviously). Another type could be  `@electronic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you plan to cite something out of a specific chapter from a publication, I suggest you use the `@incollection` entry type, along with the `natbib` citation management package and either the `plainnat` or the `IEEEtranN` bibliography style.

```
@incollection{wie:2013,
   author      = "Tomasz Wierzbicki",
   title       = "Lecture 6: Moderately Large Deflection Theory of Beams",
   booktitle   = "Structural Mechanics---MIT Course No.~2.080J",
   year        = 2013,
   organization= "Massachusetts Institute of Technology",
   address     = "Cambridge~MA",
   note        = "{MIT OpenCourseWare}",
   url         = "https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-080j-structural-mechanics-fall-2013/index.htm",
}
```

Aside: The `plain` and `ieeetr` bibliography styles are among the original BibTeX bibliography styles. They date back to the mid-1980s and they haven't been modified meaningfully since the early 1990s. Hence, they are blissfully unaware of new-fangled [!] fields such as `url`.

Look produced by the `plainnat` bibliography style:

[image]

Look produced by the `IEEEtranN` bibliography style:

[image]

Note that both looks differ quite a bit from you wrote up (which, I gather, you copied-and-paste from MIT's own website). Probably unsurprisingly, I think one is justified in deviating a bit from the citation format which appears to have been stipulated by MIT's lawyers. In particular, I see no reason whatsoever to reproduce the blurb about the Creative Commons license. (Your other bib entries don't state who the copyright holder is, do they?) Instead, I'd provide a more informative URL, in order to make it easier on your readers to track down and look up the reference for themselves.

---

The full MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@incollection{wie:2013,
   author      = "Tomasz Wierzbicki",
   title       = "Lecture 6: Moderately Large Deflection Theory of Beams",
   booktitle   = "Structural Mechanics---MIT Course No.~2.080J",
   year        = 2013,
   organization= "Massachusetts Institute of Technology",
   address     = "Cambridge~MA",
   note        = "{MIT OpenCourseWare}",
   url         = "https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-080j-structural-mechanics-fall-2013/index.htm",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}% or: {plainnat}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! I am, however, getting errors from \usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} but without that it all works fine

Comment: @Elias - What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: The first error occurrence is for the following command:
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:PersonalStatement}}

The error message I get is: 
Runaway argument?
|\@empty \<let>-command \\
Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@@ProtectSpacesFi was comp
lete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
I was also wondering, will "\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url} "clash at all with "\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}"? I am using the later to avoid hyphenation in the core of the document

Comment: @elias - It sounds like you're also loading the `nameref` package -- is this correct? This wasn't disclosed so far. Please edit your posting to indicate which packages are loaded in the preamble,  and in which order. Please also state which document class you use. On your second question: There should be no conflict between the operations of the `url` and `hyphenat` packages. The `hyphens` option of the `url` package doesn't perform any hyphenation ops; instead, the option just states that it's OK to line-break a long URL string at an existing `-` character.